# investigating a relationship at $5 \% $ level significance

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, standard-deviation

[image: question]

- $n=12$
- $\bar{x}=? $ sample average =
- $\sigma $ standard deviation =
- $\alpha =$
- $H_a :$
- Degrees of freedom if applicable
- Critical value(s) =
- Sample mean
- Standard error of mean = $\frac{\sigma } {\sqrt {n}} $
- $ = \dfrac{\bar{x}-\mu}{SE}$
- Approximate P-value =
- Decision: Reject/Accept $H_0$
- Interpret this decision:

how do i gather this  information ,is it sufficient to gather this information in order to approach this question ?

Comment: I started cleaning up your bulleted list; you can finish it if you want to.

Comment: Actually, I don't think $n=12$; 12 is  the number of categories, and I think you're interested in the number of respondents. $ \alpha =5%$ is your confidence level. I assume your initial hypothesis is that there is no connection between self-image and choice of model.

Comment: thanks @MichaelHardy and can i ask user9980 to edit my question with that update,as well,i am undegrad,i am helping a Masters student with this statistics problem

Comment: i would like to know how much $n$

Comment: @Jonas12: $n$ is the sum of totals in all entries ( I'm assuming here no one describes themselves in more than one way) , so $n=22+21+34+56$ for car model $A$, etc. $x-bar$ is , for each category, the average of each trait with respect to the total. $\alpha$ is $5$% ( some people use $\alpha =95$% ). For each car model, you test the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't think $n=12$; $12$ is  the number of categories, and I think you're interested in the number of respondents. $ \alpha =5$% is your significance level. I assume your initial hypothesis is that there is no connection between self-image and choice of model. This means that the proportion of trait -to-model is $25$%, or $ 4$-to-$1$ . Now, you need to put this claim to a test at the $5$% significant level ( or $95$% confidence level.)

Now, you need to test whether the ratios of self-image to choice-of-model differs from the initial hypothesis "enough" ( given the choice of significance level) to be accepted or rejected at that level of significance.

As an example, you want to know if a self-described 'defensive' driver is more likely to select car A, car B, or car C , etc. Then you calculate the statistic $t$ and make a decision , looking at a t-table at the $95$% confidence level. I don't remember the details of calculating the degrees of freedom; let me look it up.